# OALSimple Audio Channeling

Tags: ios, objective-c, openal, pitch, pitch-shifting

I am using OALSimpleAudio and I have a group of sounds that play in my app and I am trying to group this set of sounds into a "channel" then affect the groups pitch through that specific channel.

-(IBAction)sample001 {

```
self.sourceSample001 = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:sound001];
```

}

-(IBAction)sample002 {

```
self.sourceSample002 = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:sound002];
```

}

I need both of these sounds into 1 single channel so that I can do something like this. **Maybe?**

-(IBAction)channel1 {

```
self.channel = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] pitch:2.0f];
```

}

I'd like to change the pitch of the two sounds playing simultaneously if possible?  Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

_channelSource.pitch = 1.0;

If anybody needs the help - add the under score before hand. :)